# CSV file import using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

Is it possible to import CSV files using gem roo or using similar gem?
Also I need to bind first row of that csv file to every other rows as hash.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Did you try something? Where did you fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in CSV.

```
require 'csv'

options = { headers: true }

CSV.foreach 'path/to/file.csv', options do |row|
  puts row.to_hash
end
```